# How to convert OpenSSH ED25519 private key to the OpenSSH format that MySQL Workbench uses?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

My OpenSSH ED25519 private key file has the following structure:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

MySQL workbench will not make a connection when the file is in this format the format required is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937244/6694700):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I make this conversion (peferably with a bash command)?
I do not wish to create the key pair again and place the public key in 10's of different places.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it cannot be done because ED25519 and RSA are completely different types of keys. You cannot convert between them.

The only solution is to create a new key pair. To create on that works with MySQL use:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 8192
```

Answer (score 1):

From the post
[Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817907/165358) :

> You have an OpenSSH format key and want a PEM format key. It is not
> intuitive to me, but the suggested way to convert is by changing the
> password for the key and writing it in a different format at the same
> time.
>
> The command looks like this:
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f /path/to/key
> ```
>
> It will change the file in place, so make a backup of your current key
> just in case. `-N ""` will set the passphrase as none. I haven't
> tested this with a passphrase.
>
> The public key should be fine as is.
>
> For full explanation of the above command, see the `-m` option here:
> https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m